# Photoswipe pinch zoom behavior after the mobile site is added to home screen on iPhone

Tags: jquery-mobile, pinchzoom, photoswipe

I'm building a mobile site with jQuery Mobile and use Photoswipe to open upp images from a slider.

The problem I have is that the pinch zoom works different if the mobile web site is opened in mobile Safari or from a home screen icon.

Scenario 1 - Open the website in mobile Safari.
Everything works fine, I can click on the image in the slider and the Photoswipe layer opens up. I can swipe and pinch zoom without any problems at all.

Scenario 2 - Open up the website from an home screen icon.
When I try to pinch zoom the image there is a black screen for som milliseconds then the image shows up. I can also see that something is loaded if I look on the topbar on the phone (where the icons for wifi etc. are placed) during the "black screen flicker". This doesn't happen in scenario 1.

I use the latest versions of jQuery mobile and PhotoSwipe.

Anyone with any clues of why it behaves differently?